# How can a Spark structured streaming [2.2.x or 2.3.x] application signal that it is ready to consume from a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

## Framing the question

This question stems from the following problem:

I want to test a Spark structured streaming [2.2.X or 2.3.x] application that reads its input from Kafka (without a `from beginning` flag).

The app essentially reads like this:

```scala
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
val lines = sparkSession
                .readStream
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "test")
                .load()
```

Once the app is started and running, it may take an arbitrary amount of time for it to start listening to the Kafka topic.

**How can I post the input data to Kafka, after waiting the least time possible?**

## Naive solution

A simple solution to the problem would be to wait a large arbitrary amount of time after starting the app:

```scala
startApplication()
Thread.sleep(10*1000)
postInputDataToKafka()
```

This is problematic on 2 accounts:
 - Not all environments are equal, and some may take longer than you expected
 - It's wasteful

## Complex solution

Another option would be to use a *global supervisor*, meaning, to have some process that coordinates the test.

Meaning, the same process that starts the application waits to receive a signal from it that it's ready to listen. After this signal is received, it then starts posting the input data.

This approach requires the application to send such a signal, my question is how to do so.

Comment: What are you specifically looking to test here? That Spark can read messages that are only added to Kafka after Spark is running? Any messages added to the topic "too early" will be queued up until the Spark application is ready to read them.

Comment: @BenWatson, I'm trying to test my application. Since my application doesn't read the topic from the beginning of all time, if I send data too early, the application will not receive the messages, and I will get unexpected results. This will fail the test.

Comment: Why are you not reading the data from the last offset? I'm having difficulty understanding your use case.

Comment: As long as your application always has the same consumer ID, it will read any new messages. That is the way the majority of people test Kafka applications

Answer (score 1):

You can wait until `StreamingQuery.lastProgress` returns a non-null value, such as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery
val q: StreamingQuery = ... // start a streaming query
while (q.lastProcess == null) {
  Thread.sleep(100)
}
postInputDataToKafka
```

Comment: what would be the type of `q`?

Comment: [StreamingQuery](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery)